# Import JSON to SQL

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions

I am importing a webhook to a SQL Database via Azure Functions.

When I import using

```
{
        "remote_address": "1234",
}
```

This works.

But when I import using

```
{
        "transaction": {
            "remote_address": "1234",
    }
}
```

It doesn't work.

The Azure Function code I have is:

```
using System.Net;
using Dapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");

var successful =true;
try
{
    var cnnString  = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var rLog = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<LogRequest>();

        // insert a log to the database
        connection.Execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE] ([COLUMN]) VALUES (@remote_address)", rLog);
        log.Info("Log added to database successfully!");
    }
}
catch
{
    successful=false;
}

return !successful
    ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Unable to process your request!")
    : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Data saved successfully!");
}

public class LogRequest
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string remote_address{get;set;}
}
```

How can I get the Nested JSON Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can nest your C# classes so that they correspond to JSON structure:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string remote_address { get; set; }
}

public class LogRequest
{
    public Transaction transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Mikhail's good answer, depending on your requirements it's sometimes easiest to use `JObject/dynamic`.

```
var jobjectBody = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();
dynamic dynamicBody = jobjectBody;
string remote_address = dynamicBody.transaction.remote_address;
```

Comment: For this option how do I get it to work with the connection string?  Something like:     `connection.Execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE] ([COLUMN]) VALUES (@remote_address)", jobjectBody);`

Comment: Just pass `remote_address` to `Execute()`